# I'm attempting a scanf inside a function and outputting it to another. currently its not outputting correctly. im not sure what I'm missing

Tags: c, scanf

```
int read_number(int* value) {
    scanf("%d",&value);
    printf("%d\n",value);
}


int main() {
    int x=1;
    read_number(x);
    printf("%d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code should not even compile.  What environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your code should be:

```
int read_number(int *value) {
    scanf("%d", value);
    printf("%d\n", *value);
}


int main() {
    int x=1;
    read_number(&x);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

You pass a pointer as parameter to the function, so that it can dereference the pointer and assign the new value.

By the way, it's best practice not to use `scanf()` which is unsafe. You should use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.